# Can't set the app.config property of a dll using host app.config file

Tags: c#, wcf, app-config

I have two projects. One is  WCF service library. Another is Windows Service. Each project has its own app.config files. In windows service I am using wcf service library as refrence(.dll).In wcf service library app.config file there is a property called "DebugMode".I need to a set this property in windows service app.config file.So that it will affect the wcf service library.

but unfortunately just copy and paste the property setting is not working for me..

I am accessing property using `Properties.Settings.Default.DebugMode` syntax. C#, WPF.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
            <section name="WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
        <sectionGroup name="librarySettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
            <section name="ClassLibrary1.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <applicationSettings>
        <WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Settings>
            <setting name="HostSetting" serializeAs="String">
                <value>Foo</value>
            </setting>
        </WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Settings>
    </applicationSettings>
    <librarySettings>
        <ClassLibrary1.Properties.Settings>
            <setting name="LibrarySetting" serializeAs="String">
                <value>Bar</value>
            </setting>
        </ClassLibrary1.Properties.Settings>
    </librarySettings>
</configuration>
```

This creates two section groups in your app config of your host application. One is for the settings of the host itself and the other is for the settings that are defined in your library.